# how to make a thread-safe pre-check in golang

Tags: go

```
type ServiceDM struct {
   ServiceData *XXType
}
func (dm *ServiceDM) A() (*XXType, error) {
     if dm.ServiceData != nil {
       return ServiceDM.ServiceData, nil
     }
    // call some other services to get serviceData
    // do some logic
    ServiceDM.ServiceData = response.ServiceData
    return ServiceDM.ServiceData, nil
}
```

above is my method A() in golang, I think if it's a concurrent scenario, maybe cause race condition, how to avoid it? thank u

Comment: Add a mutex lock followed by a defer unlock in the first lines?

Comment: are you looking for https://blog.golang.org/race-detector?